# Minecraft animation, uploading a minecraft skin

Tags: faces

I don't know why but when i try to upload a minecraft skin onto a rig, the sides of the head are just lines and the back of the head is the same as the front of the head even though the skin isn't like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to **Object material properties>UV maps**. The images will show you what to do (make sure you have the body of the character selected):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Do the same for the head and you are done!

Comment: thanks, that really helped